# How to exclude Android CTS tests with configured test plan

Tags: android-source, cts

I have looked at the known-failures test plan that are available in CTS, where CTS tests that are known to fail are excluded. From there it is clear to me that you can exclude tests with this XML option:

```
 .....
 <option name="compatibility:exclude-filter" value="CtsAppSecurityHostTestCases android.appsecurity.cts.DocumentsTest#testCreateNew" />
 <option name="compatibility:exclude-filter" value="CtsAppSecurityHostTestCases android.appsecurity.cts.DocumentsTest#testCreateWebLink" />
 <option name="compatibility:exclude-filter" value="CtsAppSecurityHostTestCases android.appsecurity.cts.DocumentsTest#testEject" />
 .....
```

So I created a **my-known-failures.xml** with ~100 tests that I want to exclude. And included my **my-known-failures.xml** in the cts-suite.xml like this.

```
<configuration description="Runs CTS as a suite">
 ...
<include name="my-known-failures" />
```

And when I run cts-suite.xml I start it with the following command:

```
./${CTS_BIN} run commandAndExit cts-suite-automated --logcat-on-failure --bugreport-on-failure --screenshot-on-failure --log-level-display debug
```

The report indicates that the cts-tradefed framework has picked up my configuration:

```
Excludes:[ .... CtsAppSecurityHostTestCases android.appsecurity.cts.DocumentsTest#testCreateNew,  CtsAppSecurityHostTestCases android.appsecurity.cts.DocumentsTest#testCreateWebLink, CtsAppSecurityHostTestCases android.appsecurity.cts.DocumentsTest#testEject ... ]
```

However, it does look like these tests have been executed anyway since in the test_result.xml we see that the test cases have been given the "fail" result and the stacktrace is included:

```
<Test result="fail" name="testEjected">
    <Failure message="java.lang.AssertionError: Devices that claim to support adoptable storage must have adoptable media inserted during CTS to verify correct behavior">
      <StackTrace>java.lang.AssertionError: Devices that claim to support adoptable storage must have adoptable media inserted during CTS to verify correct behavior
    at android.appsecurity.cts.AdoptableHostTest.getAdoptionDisk(AdoptableHostTest.java:311)
    at android.appsecurity.cts.AdoptableHostTest.testEjected(AdoptableHostTest.java:251)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.DeviceTestResult$1.protect(DeviceTestResult.java:90)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.DeviceTestResult.runProtected(DeviceTestResult.java:65)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.DeviceTestResult.run(DeviceTestResult.java:94)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.DeviceTestCase.run(DeviceTestCase.java:183)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.JUnitRunUtil.runTest(JUnitRunUtil.java:55)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.JUnitRunUtil.runTest(JUnitRunUtil.java:38)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.DeviceTestCase.run(DeviceTestCase.java:148)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.HostTest.runRemoteTest(HostTest.java:463)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.HostTest.runTestClasses(HostTest.java:406)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.HostTest.run(HostTest.java:397)
    at com.android.compatibility.common.tradefed.testtype.JarHostTest.run(JarHostTest.java:142)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.suite.ModuleDefinition.run(ModuleDefinition.java:278)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.suite.ITestSuite.runSingleModule(ITestSuite.java:276)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.suite.ITestSuite.run(ITestSuite.java:225)
    at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.runTests(TestInvocation.java:793)
    at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.prepareAndRun(TestInvocation.java:476)
    at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.performInvocation(TestInvocation.java:330)
    at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.invoke(TestInvocation.java:921)
    at com.android.tradefed.command.CommandScheduler$InvocationThread.run(CommandScheduler.java:555)
</StackTrace>
    </Failure>
```

So I am confused. I know that the cts-tradefed framework does exlude some tests with the known-failure plan but when I try to do the same thing it does not work as expected.

Is it possible to  a test plan with excluded tests to the cts-suite.xml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it by using subplans feature within cts tradefed.
try to create subplan xml file with all the modules you want to run and also mention the test cases you want to exclude within the same xml file.

Command: run cts --subplan

Note: Place this xml file in /android-cts/subplans/folder
By default subplans folder will not be there, you can create it manually and provide appropriate folder permissions.

Answer (score 0):

create subplan subplan_xyz.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<SubPlan version="2.0">
<Entry include="CtsSensorRatePermissionTestCases" />
</SubPlan>
```

create subplans directory at android-cts/

copy subplan_xyz.xml at android-cts/subplans/

run cts --subplan "subplan name"

e.g.
run cts --subplan subplan_xyz